# Avoiding duplication of data with multiple one to many joins with mssql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a report to show which products our clients are using. Each client can consume multiples of each product.

```
SELECT top 100 
[First Name] = cli.FirstName
,[Last Name] = cli.FamilyName
,[Client Code] = cur.ccodcli
,[Relation] = CASE cur.crelins WHEN '1' THEN 'No relation' else 'Employee' end
,[Current Account] = cur.ccodcta
,[Savings Account] = sav.ccodcta
-- Current Accounts
  FROM [dbo].[climide] cli
  -- Customer table
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[accmctas] cur ON cli.ccodcli = cur.ccodcli
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[avimctas] sav ON cli.ccodcli = sav.ccodcli
```

I am seeing a lot of duplication of the data. There is some strange iteration happening.

```
        First_Name    Last_Name   Client_Code           Relation        Current_Account      Savings_Account
7       FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040           Employee     001001241000000432   001001211000010764
8       FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040        No relation     001005241000541729   001001211000010764
9       FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040           Employee     001001241000000432   001004211001316727
10      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040        No relation     001005241000541729   001004211001316727
11      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040           Employee     001001241000000432   001005211000447204
12      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040        No relation     001005241000541729   001005211000447204
13      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040           Employee     001001241000000432   001005211000464664
14      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040        No relation     001005241000541729   001005211000464664
15      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040           Employee     001001241000000432   001005211000541294
16      FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME  001000000040        No relation     001005241000541729   001005211000541294
```

Can someone explain how I can do multiple one-to-many joins like this and what kind of output I can expect?

Comment: Sample data and  expected results will help us help you. *Also a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` has a code smell to it, as it means the rows you get are completely arbitrary.*

Comment: I don't see what is strange about this: `accmctas` clearly has multiple rows per `ccodcli` so you got what you asked. If you want a different result you will have to aggregate, or pick exactly the row you want